# Hibernate validator programmatic constraints declaration and JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, wildfly, hibernate-validator, wildfly-8

I Have a JSF-2.2 web app on a WildFly 8.1 app server shiping Hibernate-validator 5.1

I want to set some constrainst programmaticaly using the fluent API, because they depends on the case for example a min and max of a @Size constraint could vary or a field could be @NotNull or not...

so I try to programmaticaly configure constraints such as describe here : http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-programmatic-api

I do somthing like that to try (in a EJB @Singleton @Startup):

```
HibernateValidatorConfiguration configuration = Validation
    .byProvider( HibernateValidator.class )
    .configure();

ConstraintMapping constraintMapping = configuration.createConstraintMapping();

constraintMapping
.type( Car.class )
    .property( "manufacturer", FIELD )
        .constraint( new NotNullDef() )
    .property( "licensePlate", FIELD )
        .ignoreAnnotations()
        .constraint( new NotNullDef() )
        .constraint( new SizeDef().min( 2 ).max( 14 ) );

Validator validator = configuration.addMapping( constraintMapping )
    .buildValidatorFactory()
    .getValidator();
```

But then JSF don't use this new constraints mapping.

I can submit forms without problem even if I break the constraints programmaticaly set

I don't know how to configure the Validator or ValidatorFactory JSF is using or how to provide to JSF an other Validator or ValidatorFactory...

Or may be It's more about configuring WildFly server, something to do in a config file or JNDI, I don't have a clue...

---

EDIT

I try to bind new Validator and validator factory in JNDI
But I can't because "Naming context is read-only"

```
        Hashtable jndiProperties = new Hashtable();
        jndiProperties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
        Context context = new InitialContext(jndiProperties);
        context.bind("java:comp/Validator", factory.getValidator());
        context.bind("java:comp/ValidatorFactory", factory);
```

---

Thank you Hardy

As you proposed I post Hibenate Validator improvement
https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HV-955

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way atm to do what you are after. Hibernate Validator has indeed the programmatic mapping, but it is a Hibernate Validator specific feature. There is no way to bootstrap this functionality in a Bean Validation way. I am saying this, since the only way to customize your ValidatorFactory and hence Validator instance within the container is via validation.xml. And there is no mechanism for the fluent API in this configuration file.

Your JNDI idea is in principal good, but as you say, it is only read only.

validation.xml allows for vendor specific properties though. One could imagine a property like `org.hibernate.validator.config_factory=acme.MyConfig`. The value of the property would point to a fully specified class which would contain some sort of factory method which returns the programmatic mapping to be added to the configuration. Unfortunately, such a property does not yet exist. You could open an issue [here](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HV) though ;-)